# Select row <= value

Tags: mysql, sql, sorting

So I'm currently using the following bit of SQL to select the closest rank value to the given variable but I'm looking to implement a feature so I can grab the closest rank value but nothing greater than the variable.

Here is my current SQL statement:

```
SELECT rank, points
FROM `4star`
WHERE arenaID = 6
ORDER BY ABS(rank - $v) ASC
LIMIT 1
```

`$v` indicates the PHP variable.

If this was my table:

```
+---------+----------+
|  rank   |  points  |
+---------+----------+
|   1     |    9     |
|   50    |    7     |
|  200    |    6     |
|  5000   |    4     |
|  10000  |    1     |
+---------+----------+
```

how would I select the closest rank to `3000` that was not greater than `3000`? So the row I would get would be `200 => 6`?

Answer (score 2):

> how would I select the closest rank to 3000 that was not greater than
>   3000?

Use `WHERE` to select rows where rank is less than/equal to 3000, then `ORDER BY` rank descending and `LIMIT` the results to one row:

```
SELECT rank
FROM table
WHERE rank <= 3000 AND arenaID = 6
ORDER BY rank DESC
LIMIT 1
```

Comment: Well that was rather simple... My brain always tries to over complicate things. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
SELECT rank,points 
FROM `4star` 
WHERE rank <=3000 
  AND arenaID = 6 
ORDER BY rank Desc 
LIMIT 1
```